# Is it legal to cache public Instagram photos?

Tags: web-applications, instagram

There is a highload web application which is used by `non-authenticated` users.

Now it needs to show public `Instagram` photos filtered by some hashtag. There are many `non-Instagram` users. So is it legal to cache those public `Instagram` photos on my servers to increase performance and to avoid reaching of `5000 request per hour/CLIENT_ID limits`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be posed to a lawyer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching is specifically covered in the [Instagram API Terms of Use](http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/):

```
2. You shall not:
...
Cache or store any User Content other than for reasonable periods
in order to provide the service you are providing to Instagram users.
```

So yes, it would appear legal to cache content provided it is for a reasonable period for performance purposes.

Caveat: IANAL

Comment: What's range for the reasonable periods and what about non-Instagram users ?